# Problem socket.recv() multiple python clients on C multithreaded server

Tags: python, c, multithreading, sockets, server

I am using a multithreaded server to answer possible multiple clients.

The server code (in c):

```
//C SERVER CODE
void server()
{
    int serverSocket, newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    int opt = TRUE;

    //Create socket
    serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, 
        sizeof(opt))<0)
        error("SETSOCKOPT ERROR");

    //Configure setting of the server address struct
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    //Set all bits of the padding field to 0 
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

    //Bind the address struct to the socket 
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    //Listen on the socket, with max 40 connection requests queued

    if(listen(serverSocket,40)==0)
      printf("\nListening\n");
    else
      printf("\nError\n");
      pthread_t tid[60];
      int i = 0;
      while(1)
      {
        //Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection
        addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
        newSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
        //for each client request creates a thread and assign the client request to it to process
        //so the main thread can entertain next request
        if( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, socketThread, &newSocket) != 0 )
            printf("\nFailed to create thread\n");
        else
        {
            printf("\nSOCKET CREATED\n");
        }
        if( i >= 50)
        {
            i = 0;
            while(i < 50)
            {
              pthread_join(tid[i++],NULL);
            }
            i = 0;
        }
      }
}

void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void * socketThread(void *arg)
{
    int newSocket = *((int *)arg);  
    //Send message to client socket
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    char buffer[14];
    int counter = 0;

    for (;;){
        char message[14];
        bzero (buffer, 14);
        createEthernetPacket(message);
        strcpy(buffer, message);
        write(newSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        counter = counter +1;
        printf("\r Number of packets sent: %d", counter);
    }

}
```

The ethernet packet I send is : b'A_dd_d(d)(d)_d(d)(d)_Z', where the A and Z are markers for the beginning and end of the packet, and the d are digits with the brackets representing that the digits might be there, but are not required (eg. 1 vs 12 vs 123).

These packets are created from CANBus data, which is handled by the mainloop in a multithreaded environment:

```
//9. Make threads
pthread_t thread1, thread2;

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, readCANdata, "READ_CAN");
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, server, "SERVER");
while(1==1)
{
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}
```

The client side looks like this, and is written in Python:

```
#PY CLIENT CODE
import socket
import sys
import time


def parse_data(data, last_data):
    if (len(data)>0 and data[0] == 'A' and data[-1] == 'Z'):
        valid = True
        return [data[2:-2],valid] #REMOVE START AND END MARKERS WITH SPACES
    else:
        valid = False
        return [last_data,valid]

def try_connect(address):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(address)
    connected = True
    return [client, connected]

#SETTINGS
ip=socket.gethostbyname("192.168.0.13")
port=8080
address=(ip,port)

#INITIALIZE
can_id = '0'
an1 = '0'
anVar = '0'
data = b''
last_data = "START-UP"
t0 = time.time()
connected = False

#CONNECT
while not connected:
    try:
        [client, connected] = try_connect(address)
    except:
        print('\033[91m' + "\r The server does not seem to be active. Check your settings or reboot the server." + '\033[0m', end="")

#Get data
while True:
    try:
        data = client.recv(14)
    except:
        connected = False
        try:
            [client, connected] = try_connect(address)
            data = client.recv(14)

        except:
            client.close()
            connection_status = '\033[91m' + 'DISCONNECTED' + '\033[0m'
            time_since_valid = time.time() - t0
            print('\r' + connection_status + ' Last valid packet [' + can_id + ',' + an1 + ',' + anVar + '] was received ' + str(
                    round(time_since_valid)) + ' seconds ago', end='')

    if data == b'':
        connected = False
        valid = False
        client.close()

    elif data == b'HELLO NEW SOCK':
        connected = True
        valid = True
    else:
        connected = True
        data = data.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\x00')
        [data,valid] = parse_data(data, last_data)
        last_data = data
        data_list = data.split(' ')
        can_id = data_list[0]
        an1 = data_list[1]
        anVar = data_list[2]

    if valid:
        t0 = time.time()
        t1 = time.time()
    else:
        t1 = time.time()

    time_since_valid = t1 - t0
    if connected:
        connection_status = '\033[92m'+ 'CONNECTED' + '\033[0m'
    else:
        connection_status = '\033[91m' + 'DISCONNECTED' + '\033[0m'
    print('\r'+connection_status+' Last valid packet ['+can_id+','+an1+','+anVar+'] was received '+str(round(time_since_valid))+' seconds ago', end='')
```

**Now for the problem:**

Whenever only 1 client is connected, this works perfectly. Until I start using multiple clients. Then, whenever I restart the server, all the clients disconnect (so far so good), but only a few clients reconnect. The reconnected clients are always at random and always at least one reconnects. When I print debug lines ("here 1", "here 2", etc.) it seems to stop at `client.recv(14)`.

Additionally, the server crashes when one of the clients disconnect.

**First problem solved:**

In the socket thread:

```
int newSocket = ((uintptr_t *)arg);
```

In server:

```
if( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, socketThread, (void *)(uintptr_t) newSocket) != 0 )
```

Comment: You have a race-condition in your server code: What happens if the server manages to call `accept` *twice* before the first thread fetches the descriptor value? Then the value of the first `accept` call will be lost.

Comment: Do I solve this using a `pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)` in the server and lifting it using `pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)` in the `socketThread()`?

Comment: I would solve it by passing the *value* to the thread instead. As in `pthread_create(..., (void *) (usingptr_t) newSocket)`. Then in the thread do the opposite cast: `int sock = (int) (uintptr_t) argpointer` This is one of the very few cases where it's generally considered okay to cast plain integer values to pointers and the other way around.

Comment: Does my server crash on disconnecting a client because the `write()` command has no check? I thought it had to do with the client connection error, but apparently not.

Comment: If the other end closes the connection before or during the `write` call, your process will get a `SIGPIPE` signal, which by default aborts the process. If you ignore this signal (e.g. `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`) then `write` will fail with `errno` set to `EPIPE`.

Comment: I fixed it using `send(flag = MSG_NOSIGNAL)` and afterwards checking that `!= -1`. But same idea, right? Thanks for your time!